# What is a parse object & object id?

Tags: android, json, parse-platform

This question is about [Parse](https://www.parse.com/)

From what I've found,

> Each ParseObject contains key-value pairs of JSON-compatible data. This data is schemaless, which means that you don't need to specify ahead of time what keys exist on each ParseObject. You simply set whatever key-value pairs you want.

However as a learner, I got multiple questions :

- Can I set my own `objectID` while saving data?
- Does the `objectID` varies when pushed from different devices? If so, how to retrieve those data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I set my own objectID while saving data? 
>   yes you can

```
ParseObject parseObject = new ParseObject("<ClassName>");
parseObject.setObjectId("<ObjectId>");
```

> Does the objectID varies when pushed from different devices?

every object has unique ID even if they created by the same device.